# I am trying to convert octal number to decimal number using a string as an input but the answer is coming out to be wrong

Tags: c++, string, octal

This is the given code. I am accessing each element of the string and trying to multiply it with powers of 8 but, the result is coming out to be wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int od(string s)
{
    reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
    
    int ans=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        ans=ans+s[i]*pow(8,i);
    }
    
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    
    cout<<od(s);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s[i]` is a `char` that probably does not contain the value you are expecting

Comment: "decimal" is a _string_ representation of a number. You're merely converting octal (String) to a value (int)

Comment: You should step through in a debugger and see exactly where things diverge from what you expect. Once you figure out exactly which thing doesn't do what you expect, you likely have all the information you need to research what it actually does.

Comment: `pow` also returns a floating point approximation of a result, so you're almost certainly hitting rounding errors there. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Comment: I have edited the question you can now upvote me @mattlangford

Comment: Parth, "result is coming out to be wrong." --> post input used, output seen, output expected.

Comment: Drop `reverse()` and use `ans=ans+s[i]*pow(8,i);` --> `ans = 8*ans + (s[i]-'0');`.

Comment: As usual in these questions, there is no decimal conversion anywhere to be seen, beyond the trivial `cout<<od(s);`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the line:

```
 ans=ans+s[i]*pow(8,i);
```

Here s[i] is a character. When numerical operations are performed with it, its ASCII value is taken. So here's an easy fix:

```
 ans=ans+((s[i]-'0'))*pow(8,i);
```

This will give you the correct answers for obvious reasons.

Comment: Do not use `pow` to solve integer-based problems.  Since `pow` is a floating point function, many will deem your solution as incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This code is the issue

```
ans=ans+s[i]*pow(8,i);
```

string characters (chars) are ASCII, so "0" in ASCII is actually 48. ASCII mappings are here
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

I suppose you could check each character and map it to the decimal value, or you could use something like std::stoi

```
std::stoi(myoctalstring, nullptr, 8);
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: String characters are not necessarily ASCII. But `ch - '0'` will always work when `ch` is in the range `['0' .. '9']`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues: the string's elements are digits, not numbers (`'0'` is not the same thing as `0`), and `pow` is a floating-point operation, which you should not use in conjunction with integers.

You can get the number that corresponds to a digit by subtracting `'0'` from it, and you can keep track of the current power of eight as you loop.

```
int od(string s)
{
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    int ans = 0;
    int power = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        ans = ans + (s[i] - '0') * power;
        power *= 8;
    }   
    return ans;
}
```

but it's actually simpler to not reverse the string and multiply the temporary result on each step instead:

```
int od(string s)
{
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        ans = ans * 8 + s[i] - '0';
    }   
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `atoi` or `_ttoi`, something like `atoi(s[i])`.